# How to make Keycloak accept POST requests to an authorization endpoint

Tags: keycloak, openid-connect

I am trying to integrate keycloak with an authentication service that generates JWT token and sends it via a POST request. For this, I created a custom authenticator that verifies the token and decodes the username. But I can only get the authorization code via a GET request to openid-connect/auth, POST always results in error=invalid_request.

Answer (score 1):

The authorization code flow is meant to be triggered and handled 100% in the browser, so it makes no sense to work with POST requests to get the code.

If you want to programmatically get tokens from the token service, then you should instead use the client credentials flow. In this flow you get the tokens directly without having to deal with the authentication code.

Comment: Yes you are right am using browser flow, but how can I do this programmatically can you please share any reference or GitHub repo link or any guide related that.

Comment: Try this tutorial, https://www.appsdeveloperblog.com/keycloak-client-credentials-grant-example/

To programmatically, in backend code, to get an access token, then you should use the client credentials flow.

Comment: The tutorial is ok, I understand it. But my case is different  I have N number users, they will login with their username & password then the website will returns the JWT having user info as `POST` request to `openid-connect/auth` endpoint of keycloak

Comment: Today, it is recommended to use the authorization code flow, that is the most secure flows to use. Why can't you use it? The big deal with OIDC is that it allows the user to login without having to give the client application the username/password. There are other flows , like the https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth-ropc , but that is no longer recomended,.

Comment: I am not expert of OIDC brother, I am new bee to this stuff. I am shucked at this from few days. In my case we redirect user to some website e.g `www.iam.com` on that web user will login with username & password then the `www.iam.com` will return the jwt.
see this link for better understanding with screenshots. https://keycloak.discourse.group/t/we-are-sorry-an-internal-server-error-has-occurred-on-redirection/21151
Let me add some screenshot to the post for better understanding .

Comment: What programming language are you using?

Comment: am using java for custom spi

Comment: In Java there is built-in logic/handler for dealing wit OpenIdConnect, so this part you should not do manually, https://www.baeldung.com/spring-security-openid-connect  and https://dzone.com/articles/use-java-ee-and-openid-connect-to-secure-your-java